# How does Netsparker extract the version of SQL Server during a SQL injection?

Tags: sql-injection, vulnerability-scanners, sql-server

We are using netsparker cloud version
On last week when netsparker scan it detect SQL Injection Vulnerabilities.

However I am surprised as the injection query throw error for casting and the scanner has extract SQL server version information.

> microsoft sql server 2012 (sp3) (kb3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (x64)
>   
>   oct 20 2015 15:36:27 
>    copyright (c) microsoft
>   corporation
>    web edition (64-bit) on windows nt 6.3 <x64>
>   (build 9600: ) (hypervisor)

### String used for injection

```
'AND 1=cast(0x5f21403264696c656d6d61 as varchar(8000)) or '1'='
```

When form submitted in response server throw error for casting as below.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '_!@2dilemma' to
>   data type int.

Then I tried to look on web and I found below links but the do not have information how they extract data.

http://xss.cx/examples/netsparker/www.hmficweb.hinghammutual.com_80.htm

Answer (score 1):

The variable [`@@version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177512.aspx) returns the current SQL Server version.

[Examples here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1140/how-to-tell-what-sql-server-version-you-are-running/):

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)
>
> Apr 2 2010
>   15:48:46
>
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>
> Enterprise Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Going back to basics, to manually find a SQL injection vulnerability you would inject something like

```
' OR '1'='1' UNION SELECT 1;--
```

into an input, which would make a query execute similar to the following

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name= '' OR '1'='1' UNION SELECT 1;--'
```

This would combine the results from the original, altered query, with the results from the additional `1` value column.

However, you first need to make sure the number of columns you are selecting matches the original query. So you may need to change the `1` to `1, 2`, `1, 2, 3`, `1, 2, 3, 4`, etc, until you get your values returned.

Once you get a valid result returned from the page that contains your injected values, you simply replace one of the injected values with `@@version`. e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name= '' OR '1'='1' UNION SELECT @@version,2,3;--'
```